# Mongo Aggregate Objects with $lookup using non matching values

Tags: mongodb

I've got an Object Mission referring to another object Position with a key `_p_position`.

Mission objects look like:

```
{
  _id: "ijjn97678",
  _p_position: "Position$qwerty123",
  ...
}
```

Position objects look like:

```
{
  _id: "qwerty123",
  ...
}
```

I don't know if it is Mongo or Parse convention but as one can see a `Position$` is added on relational position attribute in missions.

I'd like to aggregate both into a single Object to get a results similar to the following:

```
{
  _id: "ijjn97678",
  _p_position: "Position$qwerty123",
  positions: [
    {
      _id: "qwerty123"
    }
  ]
}
```

using:

```
missions.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      as: "position",
      from: "Position",
      foreignField: "_id",
      localField: "_p_position",
    },
  },
])
```

But I need to remove `Position$` from `_p_position`. Is there a way I can compute `"_p_position"` before it is used to find a matching Position's id ?
PS: I only have reading rights on DB

Comment: If you're using 3.6 or above, you can use [join condition](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#join-conditions-and-uncorrelated-sub-queries) . Provide samples of your collections if you need help.

Comment: @matthPen I've been looking at `join condition` and tried to use `let` to pass a variable into the `pipeline` but I can't aggregate a Position into the final object. If you can provide a piece of code it would be very much appreciated. As for a sample of collections I don't use much more than an `_id` for Position and `_p_position` in Mission

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [$addFields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/index.html) to add another field which will be then passed to `$lookup` stage. To get the part that's following the dollar sign you need: [$indexOfBytes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/indexOfBytes/#exp._S_indexOfBytes) and [$substr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/substr/) operators. Additionally dollar sign itself is a special character in Aggregation Framework (represents a field reference) so you need [$literal](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/literal/index.html) to force it to be considered as regular field

```
db.missions.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            value: {
                $let: {
                    vars: { index: { $indexOfBytes: [ "$_p_position", { $literal: "$" } ]  } },
                    in: { $substr: [ "$_p_position", { $add: [ "$$index", 1 ] } , { $strLenBytes: "$_p_position" } ] }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "Position",
            localField: "value",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "position" 
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: @theFreedomBanana this solution is not modifying your data, it's just adding temporary field for aggregation pipeline purpose, just try it :)

Comment: Worked indeed! I owe you one. Thxs